# What is the impact of COMMIT_POINT_STRENGTH parameter in Oracle DB?

Tags: oracle, commit

As per Oracle documentation, COMMIT_POINT_STRENGTH is the parameter which determines the impact of the commit of a Distributed Transaction? I have 2 database nodes in my application and COMMIT_POINT_STRENGTH is set to 1 in both nodes. If I initiate a transaction from one node for a table that exist in both nodes (by Synonyms). What happens to the transaction if the other node fails to commit data?

Comment: You may have more luck asking this question on http://dba.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 0):

First off: COMMIT_POINT_STRENGTH is *not* the parameter which determines the impact of the commit of a distributed transaction. The [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams026.htm) say:

*It specifies a value that determines the commit point site in a distributed transaction. The node in the transaction with the highest value for `COMMIT_POINT_STRENGTH` will be the commit point site.*
[...]
*The commit point site stores information about the status of transactions. Other computers in a distributed transaction require this information during Oracle's two-phase commit, so it is desirable to have machines that are always available as commit point sites.*

So given that the communication between the nodes is intact, the answer to your question "*What happens to the transaction, if other node fails to commit data?*" is independent of `COMMIT_POINT_STRENGTH` and follows Oracle's two-phase commit: **the transaction is rolled back at both nodes**.